# Python Pandas Dataframe Memory Improvement when joining strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading big file texts into Dataframes.

There is a lighter way to do this?

```py
df['New_col'] = df["CNPJ"].astype(str) + '-' + df["UF_DEST"].astype(str) + '-' +df['MES']
```

and this

```py
DIMP_1100['New_Col2'] = '1100'
```

Comment: Parallel processing might be a good way to speed this up. Have a look at [Dask dataframes](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html). As well as parallel processing they can handle data frames that do not fit in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Try these.  I'm not sure if they are faster—let me know!

Method 1 - probably not efficient since it generates lists

```
df['New_col'] = pd.Series(df[['CNPJ', 'UF_DEST', 'MES']].astype(str).values.tolist()).str.join('-')
```

More general method which might be faster

```
combine_lambda = lambda x: f"{str(x.CNPJ)}-{str(x.UF_DEST)}-{x.MES}"
df['New_col'] = df.apply(combine_lambda, axis=1)
```

The second method above might be easier to parallelize with Dask as mentioned in the comments above.

*UPDATE*:

Here's another possible method:

```
df['sep'] = '-'
df[['CNPJ', 'UF_DEST', 'MES', 'sep']].astype(str).eval("CNPJ + sep + UF_DEST + sep + MES")
```